# How to have three columns next to each other

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make it 3 columns next to each other?

[image]

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-18">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="textdiv">Text1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="textdiv">Text2</div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
               <div class="textdiv">Text3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


.row {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:75px;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
col-sm-6 {

    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
div.textdiv {
    border:1px solid #9a9a9a;

    padding:5px;
    color:black;
    font: bold 16px arila;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-right:3px;
}
div.col-sm-6 a {
    border:1px solid #9a9a9a;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:Aqua;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    font: bold 16px arila;
    width:40%;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:25px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: If you're using bootstrap it only has 12 columns http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: `col-md-18`? what is that?

Comment: i was thinking since i defined col-sm-6 x 3 =18

Comment: This has nothing to do with bootstrap! Adding your own classes to your html does not make it bootstrap, you should remove the bootstrap tag and add grid-layout tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootstrap has only 12 columns**

Please see the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Also, for the bootstrap to be correctly applied, you will have to enclose the `row`s inside a `container`.

To make it 3 columned, using bootstrap, rewrite your HTML as follows

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="textdiv">Text1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="textdiv">Text2</div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="textdiv">Text3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

For aligning the 3 columns in the same row, you will have to use the class `col-md-4` as it splits the 12 column layout into 3 equal columns.

Notice `md` in the class name. It specifies that you are targeting the medium width devices. In your code you was specifying `sm` which was for small width devices.

Comment: yes, i have tried using 12 and still the third div is not align with the other two, see my screen shot

Answer (score 2):

Taken from bootstrap, use

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="col-md-4">Test1</div>
         <div class="col-md-4">Test2</div>
         <div class="col-md-4">Test3</div>
      <div>
    </div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2):

text div width should be less than 33%.

```
width:30%;
```

add it to the txtdiv.

http://jsfiddle.net/QPKVX/372/

Answer (score 1):

change 40% to 30%
from

```
div.textdiv {
    border:1px solid #9a9a9a;

    padding:5px;
    color:black;
    font: bold 16px arila;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-right:3px;
}
```

to

```
div.textdiv {
    border:1px solid #9a9a9a;
    padding:5px;
    color:black;
    font: bold 16px arila;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-right:3px;
}
```